# Casting T from and to Generic<T> (C#)

Tags: c#, generics, casting

So I have a generic class, with Type as its generic parameter. In this class is a method, which has object parameter called value. Kinda like this:

```
public class Foo<Type> where Type : IComparable
{
    public void Bar(object value)
    {
        DoSomething((Type)value);
    }
}
```

As you can notice, I need to "DoSomething" with value (stored in object) that I first need to cast to Type. I even have my own overridden cast, which works on its own.

In this specific case, Type is generic, lets call it GenericType, and has this user-defined cast:

```
public static implicit operator GenericType<T>(T value)
{
    return new GenericType<T>(value);
}
```

and value is an enum, lets say

```
public enum Number: short
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

The 'DoSomething((Type)value)' in this case is where Type is GenericType and value is Number.Zero. For some reason, this causes the cast to throw InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. When I try it directly, i mean like..

```
GenericType<Number> z = (GenericType<Number>)Number.Zero;
```

..it works (I know, there is not explicit cast even needed). But for some reason, it does not work in the complex example I stated above. Can anyone help me understand and potentially fix that?

Comment: That's because of the fact that *casting* is a *compiler thing*, and the compiler does not verify that all possible types that can be substituted for your `<Type>` generic parameter have a cast operator. If you need to dynamically, at runtime, do the cast assuming you have supplied a value that can be casted, then you can use `dynamic` instead of `object`. However the whole premise seems wrong, why doesn't `Bar` take a parameter of `Type` to begin with?

Comment: I strongly recommend you not name your type parameter `Type`.

Comment: Step 1. Avoid casting wherever possible. Step 2: Use generic type constraints wherever you need a type to be specific in a generic. Step 3. ??? Step 4. Profit

Comment: Also know that `(SomeValueType)objectValue` is called *unboxing* and doesn't cast or convert anything, it only works if the value inside `objectValue` is **actually** a `SomeValueType`, doesn't matter that the underlying type can be cast to `SomeValueType`. So again, your whole premise seems wrong.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I'm not gonna rework it all since its not even my work - I'm just adding a functionality that needs to be there. However, changing object to dynamic helped, thanks for your help and new info for me, I'm definitely gonna find some article about dynamic keyword, since I never used it before.

Comment: Using dynamic will fail at the most unexpected of time if someone uses a type that cannot be cast to the requisite type, but it will fail at runtime, not at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just let your class use the generic type?

```
public class Foo<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public void Bar(T value)
    {
        DoSomething(value);
    }
}
```

No casting needed... and please don't use reserved words to name stuff.